# Сдвинуть элементы от кнопки в углу

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как сделать так, чтобы выделенная красным кнопка всегда была в углу, а остальные элементы при масштабировании передвигались по блоку, "игнорируя" место, над которым находится выделенная кнопка, а не заползали под нее? Подтолкните пожалуйста на верный путь, гугление не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Доработайте вопрос, добавив к нему код html и css. Так будет больше шансов на решение проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам старый добрый рабочий вариант, который будет работать везде, даже на деревяшке:

```css
.container {
  width: 260px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как такое сделать на флексах или гридах? Не могу понять

Comment: @Sevastopol' Да, убираем офтопик